# Inflate exception binary xml file on Windows

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, kotlin

I am developing an Android app using Android studio. Programming language is Kotlin and my operating system is Ubuntu. When I build project on my computer everything works fine. But when my collegue tried to do the same he has this layout inflation exception that pops up on every device we tested. Everything is the same with exception of OS. In his case it is Windows 7. Did anyone experience similar issues and in which direction I have to dig to solve this problem?

```
06-23 21:18:09.366 5457-5457/com.rbot.mdd.research E/UncaughtException: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class com.arnis.hint_keyboard.HintKeyboard
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at com.rbot.common.KotlinUtilsKt.inflateLayout(SourceFile:65)
    at com.rbot.mdd.tester.view.BotFragment.onCreateView(SourceFile:24)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:2192)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1299)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1528)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1595)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(SourceFile:758)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(SourceFile:2363)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(SourceFile:2149)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(SourceFile:2103)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(SourceFile:1984)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(SourceFile:626)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(SourceFile:166)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(SourceFile:1268)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(SourceFile:1116)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1642)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2373)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1964)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1160)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1342)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    a
06-23 21:18:09.746 5457-5457/com.rbot.mdd.research E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.rbot.mdd.research, PID: 5457
 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class com.arnis.hint_keyboard.HintKeyboard
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
     at com.rbot.common.KotlinUtilsKt.inflateLayout(SourceFile:65)
     at com.rbot.mdd.tester.view.BotFragment.onCreateView(SourceFile:24)
     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(SourceFile:2192)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1299)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(SourceFile:1528)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(SourceFile:1595)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(SourceFile:758)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(SourceFile:2363)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(SourceFile:2149)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(SourceFile:2103)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(SourceFile:1984)
     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(SourceFile:626)
     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(SourceFile:166)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(SourceFile:1268)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(SourceFile:1116)
     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(SourceFile:1642)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(SourceFile:139)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2373)
     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16538)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1964)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1160)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1342)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1047)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747
```

Comment: he might be missing the support libraries on his Computer.

Comment: Everything is the same because the code is stored in bitbucket repo.

Comment: But you install the SDK on your computer. The code can be same but the android tools being used to compile it can be different.

Comment: Check if he has android.support.v4 and  android.support.v7 support libraries on his computer.

Comment: Maybe the Proguard configuration is broken on this computer.

Comment: @android_Muncher sdk tools are the same